# Why isn't my print_linked_list_in_reverse function working?

Tags: ruby, recursion, hash, linked-list

One challenge in a Ruby course I'm doing is to print the `:data` values of the following linked list, in reverse:
`{:data=>3, :next=>{:data=>2, :next=>{:data=>1, :next=>nil}}}`
So when my method is passed the above code, it should return

```
1
2
3
```

Here's my attempt, which doesn't work for the above code. I can't figure out why, and I'd appreciate it if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong:

```
def print_list_in_reverse(hash)
  if hash[:next].nil?                       #i.e. is this the final list element?
    print "#{hash[:data]}\n"
    return true
  else
    #as I understand it, the next line should run the method on `hash[:next]` as well as checking if it returns true.
    print "#{hash[:data]}\n" if print_list_in_reverse(hash[:next])   
  end
end
```

Here's a solution, in case it helps you spot my mistake.

```
def print_list_in_reverse(list)
  return unless list
  print_list_in_reverse list[:next]
  puts list[:data]
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution relies on return values, and you don't explicitly provide one in your `else` clause.  In fact, you implicitly do because Ruby returns the result of the last statement evaluated, which for a `print` statement is `nil`.  In Ruby `false` and `nil` are both logically false, causing the `print` to get bypassed for all but the last two calls.  Your choices are to add a `true` at the end of the `else`, or make a solution that doesn't rely on return values.

To negate the need for return values, just check what logic is kosher based on info in the current invocation.  You can simplify your life by leveraging the "truthiness" non-nil objects.  Your basic recursive logic to get things in reverse is "print the stuff from the rest of my list, then print my stuff."  A straightforward implementation based on truthiness would be:

```
def print_list_in_reverse(hash)
  print_list_in_reverse(hash[:next]) if hash[:next]
  print "#{hash[:data]}\n"
end
```

The problem with that is that you might have been handed an empty list, in which case you don't want to print anything.  That's easy to check:

```
def print_list_in_reverse(hash)
  print_list_in_reverse(hash[:next]) if hash[:next]
  print "#{hash[:data]}\n" if hash
end
```

That will work as long as you get handed a hash, even if it's empty.  If you're paranoid about being handed a `nil`:

```
def print_list_in_reverse(hash)
  print_list_in_reverse(hash[:next]) if hash && hash[:next]
  print "#{hash[:data]}\n" if hash
end
```

The other alternative is to start by checking if the current list element is `nil` and returning immediately in that case.  Otherwise, follow the basic recursive logic outlined above.  That results in the solution you provided.

Comment: Thanks @pjs, your first two lines alone were sufficient, but the extra info is very helpful and greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome.  I added the rest because regardless of what Guido van Rossum says, there's more than one way to do things, and it's fun to explore the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is in the else-case. You need to return `true` to print the `hash[:data]`.

Your method always print the last 2 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Better to iterate over every value in your hash, and push the values until there's no any other hash as value inside the main hash.

```
def print_list_in_reverse(hash, results = [])
  hash.each_value do |value|
    if value.is_a? Hash
      print_list_in_reverse(value, results)
    else
      results << value unless value.nil?
    end
  end

  results.reverse
end

p print_list_in_reverse(data)
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Haha, it's a good point that just reversing the results will do it. This was actually part of an exercise that was (I think) encouraging me to find a recursive solution, but I can't deny that this works too.